# Lua attempt to call field 'PlayFile' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to create an Lua addon for Garry's Mod but I keep coming across an error in my code.
This is my code:

```
function say (Player, text, ent)
    s = "/misc/custom/"..text
    s2 = s..".mp3"
    sound.PlayFile(s2)
end
hook.Add("PlayerSay", "Say", say)
```

And this is the resulting error.

```
[saysoundtest25] lua/autorun/chatsounds.lua:4: attempt to call field 'PlayFile' (a nil value)
1. v - lua/autorun/chatsounds.lua:4
2. unknown - lua/includes/modules/hook.lua:84
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This means that `sound` exists as an object, but it does not have a member called `PlayFile`. I've never used gmod, so from what you show could it be that some code you run elsewhere has a "sound = something"? Or, less likely (because Lua is not complaining that `sound` doesn't exist, just that it doesn't have `PlayFile` as field), could it be that you need to activate something in the gmod UI or config to make the sound module available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Robotboy655 on Facepunch helped me solve this! The final code:

```
hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "Say", function( ply, text, team )
BroadcastLua( 'surface.PlaySound("misc/custom/' .. text .. '.mp3")' )
end )
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `/lua/autorun` file is serverside and there is a variable `sound` server-side Lua, however only in client side does `sound.PlayFile` exist.

```
if SERVER then
    AddCSLuaFile() -- We're the server running this code! Let's send it to the client
else -- We're a client!
-- Your code here, only ran by the client!
end
```

See [the Garry's Mod wiki](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/sound/PlayFile) for more info and note the orange box on the page which means it's client side.

Please remember to check what the function takes also:

`sound.PlayFile( string path, string flags, function callback )`

Example (taken from the wiki)

```
sound.PlayFile( "sound/music/vlvx_song22.mp3", "", function( station )
    if ( IsValid( station ) ) then station:Play() end
end )
```

Also more easy way of searching the docs:

http://glua.me/

http://glua.me/docs/#?q=sound.PlayFile

How DarkRP handles this:

https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/blob/master/gamemode/modules/chatsounds.lua#L275

Comment: @Schollii it's a game, and there is server side only functions and client side functions... in this case `sound.PlayFile` is client-side only and the autorun folder is purely server side.

Comment: I've seen a suggestion to use surface.PlaySound. The code: `BroadcastLua('surface.PlaySound(s2)')` almost works, but I end up with an error of `'PlaySound' (string expected, got nil)` If I know the exact file to play, such as "hello.mp3", then the code `BroadcastLua('surface.PlaySound("/misc/custom/hello.mp3")')` will play the sound whenever text is entered in the chat. The tricky part is making it dynamic for different inputs

Comment: That means `s2` is not a string, however this should have solved the first issue... this isn't a support form though. It's saying `s2` is `nil` try adding in a few things to debug like print and so on, it should help...

Comment: Ah you forgot the path to the file, see how before you had "/misc/custom/"..s2..".mp3"? Yeah sorry just noticed. **Edit** also when I posted that comment your answer came up! Ha, well Robotboy is a dev of gmod so I'd say he could help a lot more than I could, and I suggest using a table or an array for words with a space like "hi there" etc.